# Synopsis for a village full of characters

Tags: book, synopsis

My book is about a sleepy Devon village and is a compilation of tales that feature over thirty characters. They weave in and out of each other's stories, in the pub, Post Office and village shop etc. I had an old lady read it to see if it was too complicated but she had no problems keeping up. How can I write a synopsis for so many using only 300 words?

Comment: Welcome to the site *Owly*! Personally I think if you just switch from "My book" to "Tihs book" you are already off to a good start ;) Anyways, interesting question, though it's important to focus your question on a generic process to create a good synopsis. On Writing.Stackexchange questions should help everyone who may come later with a similar question, which is why you can use your own writing as an *example*, but you should focus on questions that will be helpful to others that have a different stroy. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: You're describing it just fine to us.  Take that and restructure it for whatever audience you're writing a synopsis for.

Answer (score 6):

What is your book about, really? Not "a Devon village". Is it about relationships? Is it about the skeletons in people's closets? Is it about the tiny day-to-day bits of kindness people do for each other?

Answer to yourself what your book is really about, then structure your synopsis around that. For example, if your book is about the skeletons in people's closets, you could start with something along the lines of:

> This story takes place in a quiet Devon village. But under the peaceful surface, every man is hiding something. As they weave through each others' lives, old secrets are revealed...

**At the core of your story is not a place or a character, but an idea.** Formulate your synopsis around the idea. Tell a little of how the idea is expressed by means of the settings, the characters, etc.